# how to use IF and ELSE statements with both text and numerical columns

Tags: sql

```
SELECT     DATASET, BLOCKID, CATEGORY, ROUND(TONNES, 0) AS TONS, ROUND(VOLUME, 0) AS VOLUME, ROUND(EU3O8, 0) AS GRADE, ROUND(TONNES * EU3O8 / 1000, 0) 
                      AS Metal_kg
FROM         dbo.tblPTEvaluationRep_GC75ppm
```

[image: Picture]

I can do basic calculations, I however now need to use what I think are "IF and ELSE" statements, but am unable to.

The last column, Metal_kg should be IF CATEGORY = 'WST'or 'SEM' THEN '0' ELSE TONNES*EU3O/1000

There are more categories than those listed in picture.

I am unable to get any answer or it is unable to calculate my equation.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 'When Case' in SQL query like below :

```
SELECT DATASET,
       BLOCKID,
       CATEGORY,
       ROUND(TONNES, 0) AS TONS,
       ROUND(VOLUME, 0) AS VOLUME,
       ROUND(EU3O8, 0) AS GRADE,
       CASE
         WHEN CATEGORY IN ('WST', 'SEM') THEN 0
         ELSE ROUND(TONNES * EU3O8 / 1000, 0)
       END AS Metal_kg
FROM dbo.tblPTEvaluationRep_GC75ppm
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL uses `case` instead of `if`:

```
CASE WHEN CATEGORY IN ('WST','SEM') THEN '0'
                                    ELSE TONNES*EU3O/1000
 END
```

More about `case`:

- https://modern-sql.com/feature/case